# Ruby Keyword Arguments in C Extensions

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

How does one handle Ruby 2.0.0 keyword arguments from a C extension?

**Background**

```
def example(name: 'Bob' hat_color: 'red')
  puts "#{name} has a #{hat_color} hat!"
end

example                                  #=> "Bob has a red hat!"
example(name: 'Joe', hat_color: 'blue')  #=> "Joe has a blue hat!"
```

Keyword arguments (like the above) are quite useful when handling methods that have a lot of different call sequences or options. I have one such method in a C extension (a `blit` method that handles most of the OpenGL drawing in my project) and I am wondering how I might have the method handle keyword arguments from ruby.

**Ideas**

Based on some research I have done, I think that such handling might be done through the `:` option on the [`rb_scan_args`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/class.c#1598) C function. However, I have been unable to find any information on how to use it to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no core method that currently uses keyword arguments directly, i.e. `klass.instance_method(:method).parameters` will never return `:key` for builtin classes.

You probably have to define a method that accepts an argument, in this case a hash and parse it yourself. To do so, you can use `rb_scan_args` with the `:` argument to get a `Hash` from the last argument (e.g. `dir_initialize`) or code similar to the `OPTHASH_GIVEN_P` macro (in `array.c`). From the hash, you could use `rb_get_kwargs` to get the values you want. I haven't looked into how to generate an error for unrecognized keyword arguments if you desire. I think most core methods don't do this check (at least yet).

You could have your method defined in Ruby using the keyword elements and call an internal C method from there. This would give you for free unknown keys being checked and a proper `parameters` signature.

I hope to improve this situation with a revised api to define methods in Ruby 2.2 that would make it more natural to have keyword arguments in C functions, among other things (see [this issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8088))

Comment: Ok, thanks! If keyword arguments can not be handled by the C extension API, then what does the `:` option to `rb_scan_args` do?